# How do I increase character length capability when saving an Excel Sheet into a text file?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below saves the active sheet to a text file. The problem is that it produces a crazy output having some part of a line printed on some other row.

Here is the code I have

```
Sheets("TreeEng.xml").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=thisWB.path & "\TreeEng.txt", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter ' //Save as text (tab delimited) file
If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then '//Double sure we don't close this workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End If
```

And here is the output it produces:

```
<DATAPACKET>
    <ROWDATA>
        <ROW TITLE="Israel" INDENT="0" HREF="01_01_Introduction_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title2" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Distinctive Features of the Employment Environment" INDENT="1" HREF="02_01_Distinctive Features of the Employment Environment_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title3" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Key Changes in Recent Years" INDENT="1" HREF="03_01_Key Changes in Recent Years_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title3" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Key Breakpoints Related to Number of Employees" INDENT="1" HREF="04_01_Key Breakpoints Related to Number of Employees_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title3" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Start of Employment" INDENT="1" HREF=" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title3" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Contract of Employment" INDENT="2" HREF="05_01_Contract of Employment_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title4" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Non-Compete and Other Clauses" INDENT="2" HREF="05_02_Non-Compete and Other Clauses_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title4" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Framework for Employee Participation and Representation" INDENT="2" HREF="07_01_Framework for Employee Participation and Representation_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title4" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Collective Bargaining" INDENT="2" HREF="07_02_Collective Bargaining_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title4" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
        <ROW TITLE="Industrial Action" INDENT="2" HREF="07_03_Industrial Action_ETCISR.htm" HREF_JD="" IMG="" STYLE="" INCLUDE="" CODE="" CLASS="tree_title4" DXPARSE="TRUE" ENABLED="TRUE" />
    </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

If you check rows 3,5 and 9, it doesn't end in what it needs to be ending with, rather, the closing parts of the line are placed somewhere below.

How do I fix this?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249885

Comment: Tim Williams wrote a link
its amazing! it works! [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344655/how-do-i-increase-character-length-capability-when-saving-an-excel-sheet-into-a#_=_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344655/how-do-i-increase-character-length-capability-when-saving-an-excel-sheet-into-a#_=_)